# Eclipse - how to git clone --depth 1

Tags: eclipse, jgit, shallow-clone

I have to import a quite big (bitbucket) git repository in Eclipse.
Right now Eclipse is stuck cloning from an hour.
To speed up things I'd like to clone it in "shallow" mode (just taking the last commit).

I tested this with the CLI `git clone --depth 1 https://bitbucket.myco.local:8443/scm/big/quite-big-project.git` and it worked well: it took less than 2 minutes. Anyway I have to clone the project into eclipse and have no idea about how to set the depth in Eclipse's git import project wizard.

Comment: This sort of thing is why it's important to distinguish between different Git implementations: different ones have different features, bugs, and so on. For instance go-git does not yet support push options in any official release. (jgit does some things right on Windows that command-line Git doesn't, e.g., distinguish between branches FOO and foo.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, [JGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/), the pure Java implementation of git used by Eclipse does not yet support the `--depth` option:

```
$ jgit clone --depth=1 https://github.com/eclipse-linuxtools/org.eclipse.linuxtools.eclipse-build.git
fatal: "--depth" is not a valid option
```

There is bug open for it over at bugzilla: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=475615

I would recommend cloning it via the normal git command line, and then using the "add existing local repo" button from the Git perspective:

[image: Click here to view a screenshot]

Comment: Note that meanwhile https://git.eclipse.org/r/c/jgit/jgit/+/193329 was merged, and we can expected support for shallow fetch / clone as part of JGit 6.3.0 in mid-September :-)

Comment: However, that's currently "only" for the API; the feature is not exposed to the CLI yet.

Comment: As of Sep 25, 2022, the [latest version](https://central.sonatype.dev/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/6.3.0.202209071007-r) already supports shallow clone. Hooray!

Answer (score 0):

I worked-around like this (in a way similar as what suggested @mboot):
1> I cloned the repository with CLI and `--depth 1` option
2> I followed the procedure of import from git using "filesystem" protocol
3> Unbound the "filesystem" origin (`git remote remove origin`)
4> Added the "actual" remote `git remote add origin https://bitbucket.myco.local:8443/scm/big/quite-big-project.git`
5> Hoped for the best

Answer (score 0):

android 13 can use jgit 6.3.0 ( shallow depth ) now

(Because jgit 6.3.0 user OutputStream.transferTo method )
[see android 13 api 33](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E32bA.png)